# Objective-C casting super class to subclass

Tags: objective-c, casting, selector

I have 2 classes:

- NWStorePackage
- NWStorePackageConsumable

the NWStorePackageConsumable is a subclass of NWStorePackage (which is designed for non consumable content).

I recently added the NWStorePackageConsumable to the project. All throughout the code i'm using NWStorePackage.

i have a class constructor to create the proper instances.

```
+ (id) storePackageFromStorePackageDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionary
```

This returns a NWStorePackageConsumable or NWStorePackage depending on the dictionary content.

When some action recuires some consumable related stuff i check the package type (enum defined in NWStorePackage). if that type is set to type of a consumable product i cast the NWStorePackage instance to a NWStorePackageConsumable instance and call the method below. I suppose that the casting won't be a problem since i created them properly earlier.

```
- (id) updateConsumableCount: (int) increase;
```

This generates the following error:

```
-[NWStorePackage consumableCount]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c34380
```

Here is the complete code where a call the method

```
for(NWStorePackage *storePackage in _storePackagesArray) {
    if ([storePackage purchased]) {
        NWStorePackageStorage *sps = [NWStorePackageStorage storePackageStorageWithProductIdentifier:storePackage.productIdentifier andIsPurchased:storePackage.purchased];

        if ([storePackage packageType] == StorePackageTypeConsumable) {
            NWStorePackageConsumable *consumable = (NWStorePackageConsumable *) storePackage;
            [sps setConsumableCount: [consumable consumableCount]];
        }
        [purchases addObject:sps];
    }
}
```

The method below is my constructor for NWStorePackage, i don't override it in NWStorePackageConsumable.

```
+ (id) initWithContentsOfDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionary {
NSLog(@"Initializing NWStorePackage with dictionary content", kLOGLEVEL_STORE);

for (id key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"Key: %@ :: Value: %@", kLOGLEVEL_STORE, key, [dictionary objectForKey: key]);
}
NWStorePackage *package = [[NWStorePackage alloc] init];
[package setPackageID:[(NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue]];
[package setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
[package setProductIdentifier:[dictionary objectForKey:@"productIdentifier"]];
[package setDescriptionLong:[dictionary objectForKey:@"descriptionLong"]];
[package setDescriptionShort:[dictionary objectForKey:@"descriptionShort"]];
[package setPackageType: (StorePackageType) [[dictionary valueForKey:@"type"] longValue]];

return package;
```

}

Comment: seems like *packageType* is incorrectly set? i.e. you're setting it to * StorePackageTypeConsumable* on an *NWStorePackage* instance. What class do you pass to *-alloc* in your factory method?

Comment: Why use `packageType`? Just use `[storePackage isKindOfClass:[NWStorePackageConsumable  class]]`

Comment: bryan: because i need to know what type it is, starting from a dictionary. Anyway, it just hit me what was the problem from nielsbot's comment. the class constructor was still generating the wrongful type. i got rid of it and changed it into a real constructor. thanks for jolting my brain :)

Comment: "unrecognized selector" is always right.  When it says it was "sent" a NWStorePackage, it was sent an NWStorePackage.  Your task is generally to figure out why the class is not the expected type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed class constructor to this

```
- (id) initWithContentsOfDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionary {
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    NSLog(@"Initializing NWStorePackage with dictionary content", kLOGLEVEL_STORE);

    for (id key in dictionary) {
        NSLog(@"Key: %@ :: Value: %@", kLOGLEVEL_STORE, key, [dictionary objectForKey: key]);
    }

    [self setPackageID:[(NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue]];
    [self setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [self setProductIdentifier:[dictionary objectForKey:@"productIdentifier"]];
    [self setDescriptionLong:[dictionary objectForKey:@"descriptionLong"]];
    [self setDescriptionShort:[dictionary objectForKey:@"descriptionShort"]];
    [self setPackageType: (StorePackageType) [[dictionary valueForKey:@"type"] longValue]];
}

return self;
```

}

and convenience method to this

Answer (score 1):

In general you should try to replace 'instanceof' logic with polymorphism. So rather than:

```
if (myObject isKindOfClass:[NWStorePackageConsumable class])
   //doSomething
else if //etc
```

. . . try to identify an abstract method that is common to both classes, and create a specific implementation in each sub-class. For example:

```
[storePackage deliver]; //This will be different depending on consumable or not.
```

If you're not able to do this, then it might indicate that the two classes shouldn't really share a common ancestor.

**Abstract Base Class vs protocol vs Class Cluster:**

- Use an abstract base class when you have a common framework, where some specifics will be handled by sub-classes.
- Use a a protocol where you want to create a common contract, but the implementation between instances will be very different.
- Use a Class Cluster (a variation on the Abstract Factory pattern) in the same cases you'd use an abstract base class, and when you also want that common class to contain the logic that decides which concrete instance will be returned "behind the scenes".

**To Debug the issue:**

Are you trying to cast an instance of the base class to a sub-class? This is not possible (under normal circumstances - you could do some isa pointer swizzling, but you don't want to). You need to decide up-front want instance your class should be. The purpose of the base class is to present a common interface to consumers, that don't have to care what happens behind the scenes in order to conform to that interface.

With a debugger, check that your instance *is* actually an instance of the sub-class.